# Converting all the DateTime Columns to SqlDateTime Columns in a Datatable

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, datatable, type-conversion

What I want to do is basically take ***any generic*** DataTable and then 
Convert all the DateTime columns into SqlDateTime Columns. (i.e if the datetime column value = datetime.MinValue then Set it to SqlDateTime.Null)

Is there anyway I can do this without altering the original datatable (i.e withoutadding computed columns ) or having to parse through then entire datatable row by row?

The reason I want to do this is because I need to feed this Datatable into a SQLBulkCopy method, which would write them all together into the database. The problem with using datetime field is that it throws an error at the time of upload.

AgentX

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best i could come up with was this,

I know it is copying the datatable row by row, I believe it can be done more elegantly with LINQ ,

any one else has an answer?

```
                Dim dtOut As DataTable = dt.Clone()
                For Each c As DataColumn In dtOut.Columns
                    If c.DataType.FullName = GetType(DateTime).FullName Then
                        c.DataType = GetType(SqlTypes.SqlDateTime)
                    End If
                Next

                dtOut.BeginLoadData()
                Dim drtmp As DataRow
                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    drtmp = dtOut.NewRow()
                    For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                        If dc.DataType.FullName = GetType(DateTime).FullName Then
                            If dr(dc) = Date.MinValue Then
                                drtmp(dc.ColumnName) = SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null
                            Else
                                drtmp(dc.ColumnName) = dr(dc)
                            End If
                        Else
                            drtmp(dc.ColumnName) = dr(dc)
                        End If
                    Next
                    dtOut.Rows.Add(drtmp)
                Next
                dtOut.EndLoadData()
```

Comment: Are you missing a `dtOut.Rows.Add(drtmp)` ?

Comment: Also, you might want to remove the definitions for variables `i` & `j`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ChangeDateTimeColumn(DataTable newDataTable)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < newDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < newDataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            DataColumn dc = newDataTable.Columns[j];
            if (dc.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                string name = dc.ColumnName;
                DataRow row = newDataTable.Rows[i];
                if (row[name] != null && row[name].ToString().Trim() != "")
                {
                    DateTime value = (DateTime)row[name];
                    if (value < (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue)
                    {
                        row[name] = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue;
                    }
                    else if ((DateTime)SqlDateTime.MaxValue < value)
                    {
                        row[name] = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MaxValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```